# regex to replace mailto: hrefs but ignore site links

Tags: php, regex

I need some help to tweak this regular expression:

```
$content = 'more <a href="http://www.test.com">test</a> test <a href="mailto:jeff@test.com">Jeff</a> this is a <a href="http://www.test.com">test</a>';

$content = preg_replace("~<a .*?href=[\'|\"]mailto:(.*?)[\'|\"].*?>.*?</a>~", "$1", $content);
```

This expression is to strip the html markup off a mailto link and just return the email (jeff@test.com)

It works fine except for in the example I gave above - because a unlimited number of whitespaces is allowed before the href in the pattern, when a website link is before the mailto link, the regex looks all the way forward until it finds the mailto: in the following link and removes all the content in between.

maybe a fix would be to just limit it to two or three whitespaces after the opening tag so as  to not look so far ahead, but i wonder if there is a better solution from people who know regex better than I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not to allow any amount of whitespace, that would be working. The problem is you allow one space and any amount of *ANY* character with your `<a .*`

If you fix this and allow really only whitespace like this

```
<a\s+href=[\'|\"]mailto:(.*?)[\'|\"].*?>.*?</a>
```

it seems to work.

See it [here at Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ut35)

But probably you should have a closer look at alex answer (+1 for the example) as this would be the cleaner solution.

Comment: thank you! yes, i agree about alex's solution and I'm going to study that and learn domdocument  better after this. but you fixed my problem straight off (unfortunately, something is a little wonky on the page with Alex's) so you get the check

Answer (score 6):

Here is what you *should* be using...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($content);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a) {
    if ($a->hasAttribute('href') 
        AND strpos($href = trim($a->getAttribute('href')), 'mailto:') === 0) {

         $textNode = $dom->createTextNode(substr($href, 7));
         $parent = $a->parentNode;
         $parent->insertBefore($textNode, $a);
         $parent->removeChild($a); 

    }   
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bxbWTP).

`$dom->saveHTML()` adds all the HTML boiler plate stuff such as `html` and `body` element, you can remove them with...

```
$html = '';
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $node) {
    $html .= $dom->saveHTML($node);
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3xVova).

Comment: thanks alex! this definitely works on my example, but in the application itself it is messing up the page.. the content I am giving it is just the contents of a posted comment (blog-type comment)

can this be modified to make these changes to the $content var so I can return it normally?

Comment: @jmadsen: Just strip out the `html` boilerplate stuff.

Comment: sorry - don't understand what you mean :-(

Comment: or use XPath `a[@href=starts-with(., 'mailto')]`